# Creating an installer that installs two programs?

Tags: installation, electron

I have an electron app that I want my users to be able to install. However, a dependency of this app is a C++ package that I have compressed in a .zip file. I need the user to unzip this file and put it into a certain directory under Program Files (target platform is windows). Is it possible to create an installer that both installs the electron app and contains a payload that it can unzip and put into that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. An Electron app is just a bunch of files that you can package however you want. A great tool for packaging Electron apps is [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build)

`electron-builder` uses [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) by default to build Windows setups. It also provides a way to [customize the NSIS script](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script)

> If you want to include additional resources for use during installation, such as scripts or additional installers, you can place them in the build directory and include them with File. For example, to include and run extramsi.msi during installation, place it in the build directory and use the following:

```
!macro customInstall
  File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\extramsi.msi "${BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR}\extramsi.msi"
  ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$PLUGINSDIR\extramsi.msi" /passive'
!macroend
```

In your case, instead of `extramsi.msi`, you'll probably want to include [`7zip standalone console version`](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and your additional `.zip` file. You can use this custom script to extract this file to wherever you want